# XPath to extract text with multiple tags, in iOS using libxml2

Tags: ios, xpath, libxml2

At iOS app with libxml2, while parsing this HTML piece (it's part of a big page) -

```
...
<span class="ingredient">
    <span class="amount">
        <span class="value">500 </span> 
        <span class="type">g</span>
    </span>    
    <a href="...">bread flour</a> 
    or 
    <span class="ingredient">
        <span class="amount">
            <span class="value">500 </span> 
            <span class="type">g</span>
        </span>  
        <span class="name">
            <a href="...">all-purpose flour</a>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
...
```

I need to extract only the text: "500 g bread flour or 500 g all-purpose flour".

The parsed NSDictionary result of `//span[@class="ingredient"]` XPath query returned -

```
{
    nodeAttributeArray =     (
                {
            attributeName = class;
            nodeContent = ingredient;
        }
    );
    nodeChildArray =     (
                {
            nodeAttributeArray =             (
                                {
                    attributeName = class;
                    nodeContent = amount;
                }
            );
            nodeChildArray =             (
                                {
                    nodeAttributeArray =                     (
                                                {
                            attributeName = class;
                            nodeContent = value;
                        }
                    );
                    nodeContent = 500;
                    nodeName = span;
                },
                                {
                    nodeAttributeArray =                     (
                                                {
                            attributeName = class;
                            nodeContent = type;
                        }
                    );
                    nodeContent = g;
                    nodeName = span;
                }
            );
            nodeContent = "";
            nodeName = span;
        },
                {
            nodeAttributeArray =             (
                                {
                    attributeName = href;
                    nodeContent = "http://www.food.com/library/flour-64";
                }
            );
            nodeContent = "bread flour";
            nodeName = a;
        },
                {
            nodeAttributeArray =             (
                                {
                    attributeName = class;
                    nodeContent = ingredient;
                }
            );
            nodeChildArray =             (
                                {
                    nodeAttributeArray =                     (
                                                {
                            attributeName = class;
                            nodeContent = amount;
                        }
                    );
                    nodeChildArray =                     (
                                                {
                            nodeAttributeArray =                             (
                                                                {
                                    attributeName = class;
                                    nodeContent = value;
                                }
                            );
                            nodeContent = 500;
                            nodeName = span;
                        },
                                                {
                            nodeAttributeArray =                             (
                                                                {
                                    attributeName = class;
                                    nodeContent = type;
                                }
                            );
                            nodeContent = g;
                            nodeName = span;
                        }
                    );
                    nodeContent = "";
                    nodeName = span;
                },
                                {
                    nodeAttributeArray =                     (
                                                {
                            attributeName = class;
                            nodeContent = name;
                        }
                    );
                    nodeChildArray =                     (
                                                {
                            nodeAttributeArray =                             (
                                                                {
                                    attributeName = href;
                                    nodeContent = "http://www.food.com/library/flour-64";
                                }
                            );
                            nodeContent = "all-purpose flour";
                            nodeName = a;
                        }
                    );
                    nodeContent = "";
                    nodeName = span;
                }
            );
            nodeContent = "";
            nodeName = span;
        }
    );
    nodeContent = or;
    nodeName = span;
}
```

The problem is that "nodeContent" of the dictionary root is the text " or ", and all tags are sitting as children of the root node, so order of the pieces was lost - I can't tell that or is actually in the middle and while concat of all text, I get the following string: "or 500 g bread flour 500 g all-purpose flour".

Can any one figure out a way to extract the pure text in 1 XPath query, or alternatively use the XPath engine to read an ordered list of elements?

Comment: You're writing about some query, but not showing it. :)

Comment: I didn't think it's relevant, but maybe I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need *all text nodes*, this can easily be done using

```
//text()
```

which will return all nodes. There are some issues with white space in your contents, you can ommit all whitespace-only nodes using

```
//text()[not(matches(., '$[\s]+$', 'm'))]
```

You will still need to do some trimming (eg. "g ") in Objective C afterwards, but you should get an in-order result set of all text nodes containing printable characters.

Comment: The given HTML is only a part of the whole page, getting all text elements won't help in this case. I'll update my question. Thanks!

Comment: But this was a good lead - using //span//text() it returned all text elements ordered correctly.